# elasticsearch to apply a sort to a query, the select top N for aggregate

Tags: elasticsearch

The query below aggregates over the entire result of the query, and size only affects what is returned rather than what is aggregated.

How would I modify the search so that only the top N results after sort is processed by the average aggregation?

It seems such a simple requirement that I'm expecting it to be possible but so far all my efforts have failed, and similar questions on SO have gone unanswered.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "jobType": "LiveEventScoring"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "host": "MTVMDANS"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "dataSourceCode": "AU_VIRT"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "measurement": "EventDataLoadFromCacheDuration"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "timestamp": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "avgDuration": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "elapsedMs"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "size only affects what is returned rather than what is aggregated" - didnt get this part

Comment: What I meant is that"size": 0 just causes no query results to be returned to the client, where as setting "size": 100 would mean return first 100 results of query, but in either case the average would be done over entire result set. I'm just pointing out that I can't use "size" to achieve the top N aggregation.